# Send message using SMSManager android

Tags: android, sms

In my application, I am sending a message to particular number in background using SMSManager. I have registered receivers to verify sent status, delivery status of my message. This works fine. But when I send a message, if phone number is switched off or SIM card is removed and switched on again or SIM card is reinserted, my messages are not being sent. How to achieve this functionality?

SMS Manager code

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Receivers:

```
smsSentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {


            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

                switch(getResultCode())
                {

                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sms failed due to generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "could not send the message due to unavailability of service.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                }

            }
        };

            smsDeliveredReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver () {

            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch(getResultCode())
                {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not Delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }

                }

            };

            registerReceiver(smsSentReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));
            registerReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED ));

    }
```

Comment: post your sms manager code

Comment: are you sure its not delivering after the device is in range or switched on??

Comment: ya sure i checked it.I don't know why.

Comment: register your reciver in manifest file..

Comment: Tried with that also,no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can achieves this by using "Broadcst Reciver". When a phone is switched on you will receives a broadcat reciver like new sim is inserted, and try to use pending intent also.